# Make git NOT to remember history of one file

Tags: git

I want to configure git repository so it will NOT remember the history of one long file, but still will keep its latest version.

Is it possible?

**P.S.** Thank you for the answers --- I am convinced now that I do not want to do that.

Comment: do you want to ignore this file for further commit ?

Comment: You probably need [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/). It doesn't do what you asked for but it does what you actually want: it doesn't use **local** disk space for previous versions of the file.

Comment: @ruhul, no on each commit I want to update the long file and wipe out its history.

Comment: @axiac it is related, but not what I want.

Comment: Can you please expand on your use-case? Why do you want git to not behave like git?

Answer (score 3):

So...  Several people (comments and Hauleth's answer) are recommending solutions like LFS, which efficiently manage large file needs in git repos.  It seems nobody's quite sure why you would want the behavior you specified, rather than the behavior these give... and that's for good reason.  A big part of the purpose of git is to be able to reproduce past versions of your code.  If we compare your desired behavior to LFS, the big difference is that under your desired behavior it becomes impossible to reproduce a prior version of the system.  So it really isn't clear *why* you would want that.

But that's fine... let's get to your question.

Can it be done?  Well... by hobbling git so that it can't perform even basic source control functions properly, you could fake it.  But it won't be easy and git will work against you every step of the way.  Sound good?

And before you go asking "what about RsrchBoy's solution"... that's the one that would involve hobbling git's ability to work with your repo.  Where they see your question "[implying that you're] ok with editing the commit history", I see it showing that you aren't aware of the consequences of constantly editing your commit history.

It's hard to do correctly, especially as part of a routine workflow.

It's made harder because by definition, your use case requires editing the history either (a) with staged changes pending commit, or (b) right after committing changes that you don't want to edit.

Once you get it working right, every time you do it the refs will be moved in a non-fast-forward way, putting everyone else who shares the repo in a bad state.  If they do the wrong thing to recover from that state, extra copies of the file can pop back into the history.  And even if everyone plays along, keeping the remote from hoarding all those obsolete copies of the file is still likely to be quite difficult (depending on how your remote is hosted).

Maybe those last concerns don't worry you, because maybe you're the only user of your repo and maybe you don't keep a remote.  If that's the case - if you're not using git for its key strengths as a distributed version control system, and you're trying to do something against the grain of its history-tracking model - then git may just not be the best tool for your use case.

Or, as others have implicitly suggested, maybe it's the use case that needs to be reassessed.  That's between you and whoever else might be on your team.

Comment: Thank you --- you convinced me that I do not want it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change past commits without invalidating whole history, it is just how Git works. So if this is big file that need to be versioned, but it's versioning is infeasible via Git then you have alternatives in form of:

- [Git Annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com)
- [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com)

Which allows you to have separate tree that stores blobs outside of "standard" Git's tree.

Comment: Section "Git Internals" in "Pro Git" describes a way to wipe out a large file from the history --- I thought maybe there is a script which does in an automatic way --- apparently not.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin the problem is that this solution rewrite whole history. So this is useful when you accidentally tracked large, generated, file. If I understand your usecase correctly, then this is completely different.

Answer (score -1):

Your question implies that you're ok with editing the commit history, as that's the only way to do what you're asking.  Look at the

```
git filter-branch
```

command, as it'll do what you're asking.  Leaving the latest revision of the file in question in place is left as an exercise for the reader (though I'd just go and commit it back in after `filter-branch` has done its thing).

Be aware that depending on the history and usage patterns of the repository this will have significant implications.  (OTOH, if it's a repo only you use, those implications are probably less.)

If you're just looking to cut down on the clone/repo size, performing shallow clones (or making your clone shallow) may do what you want with no *global* implications for other consumers of the repository.  (See `git-fetch` and `git-clone` for more information about shallow.)